# Catalan number variation? or generalization?

Tags: probability, reference-request, catalan-numbers

I came a cross with the following number
$$ C_{n}(m) = \frac{1}{n+m+1}\binom{m+2n}{n} $$
where $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$.
When $m=0$, it is a well-known [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Generalizations).

I am curious about whether this number is somewhat known/studied in somewhere? 
If yes, I would like to take a look on it.

I am trying to search this quantity but what I've got so far so-called 'super-Catalan' number which is not related...

Any comments/suggestions will be very appreciated.

[Edited: $\frac{1}{n+1} \to \frac{1}{n+m+1}$.]

Comment: You are aware that this is not always an integer?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Sure, when $m=n=1$, $C_1(1) = 3/2$.